# Halide: OpenCL code generation

Tags: halide

Is it possible in Halide to produce a file which contains generated OpenCL code? I have tried to produce a c file from a Halide program which target would be opencl, but I don't see any opencl specfic code there.

Edit 1:

I would like to see especially how kernels are created in Halide. Something like this:

`static char
kernelSourceCode[] = 
kernel void test_kernel(int a, int b, __global int *out)
{
    out[0] = a + b;
}`

Edit 2:

Ok, I put HL_DEBUG_CODEGEN=1 to env variable and set in the code set_target(Target::Debug). I got bunch of code on the screen, which some of were OpenCL code but I still can't see any kernel spesific code.

There are two lines on the screen which indicates about kernels. Should there be something?

`OpenCL kernel:
/*OpenCL C*/`

Then there is also a line:

`kernel void _at_least_one_kernel(int x) { }`

In example if I have a function like this:

`gradient(x, y) = x + y;`

Is the function inside a kernel if I want to target to OpenCL?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I managed to spot from [documentation](http://halide-lang.org/docs/tutorial_2lesson_12_using_the_gpu_8cpp-example.html)

CUDA or OpenCL are not enabled by default. You have to construct a Target object, enable one of them, and then pass that target object to compile_jit.

```
Target target = get_host_target();
target.set_feature(Target::OpenCL);
curved.compile_jit(target);
```

---

Or similarely you can use `compile_to` method, by providing the correct target.

```
EXPORT void Halide::Func::compile_to(const Outputs & output_files,
                                     std::vector<Argument> args,
                                     const std::string& fn_name,
                                     const Target& target = get_target_from_environment() 
)
```

Comment: I am using "compile_to_c" function to produce a c source file from Halide code. I would like to get somehow similar file or output to see what opencl code Halide produces. Or to know if it is even possible.

Comment: Check the updated answer, there is also `compile_to` method which might be more suitable for you